# Python Warning: Input is not a terminal (fd=0)

Tags: python, stdin

I'm trying to create a terminal-based application in Python 3 that is executed within another program (clion).

At first I was using `prompt-toolkit`, but simple `input` does the same. Every time I run the application within the other program the following error comes up:

`Warning: Input is not a terminal (fd=0).`

Is there another way to get the input from python?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to address this? I am running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Python curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), a cool lib that let you interact directly with the terminal. I don't know if your project requires this much of low-level but you could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking it now, but it looks like it still can't find the terminal, it gives a different message tho: `_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal`

Comment: Do you run the program directly inside CLion ? If you are, go to Run/Debug configurations (the button at the left of the run button on the upper right corner of the IDE) modify the running configuration of the script and check the "Emulate terminal in output console" option